# how to partition the range of a variable given different conditions?

Tags: python, algorithm

For a given program, now I want to determine the valid input range corresponding to different paths.

For an example:

```
def test(a):

    if (a < 50):
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
```

So for this program, there are two path. One path returns 1 and another returns -1. Assume there is a given function (you can also design your own function) that can return a list of path conditions:

```
conditions = get_path_conditions(test)
```

so that the conditions contain 2 string elements, `["a<50", "a>=50"]`

Assume the range of input `a = "(-100,100)"` (for convenience, I use a string to represent the lower bound and upper bound， just like we do in math. You could also use other representations if you like).

So how do I design a function that can map different conditions into different input ranges?

```
conditions = ["a<50", "a>=50"]
a = "(-100,100)"
input_ranges = get_inputs(conditions,a)
```

So that `input_ranges` has 2 elements: `["(-100,50)","[50,100)"]`

Similar questions:

http://acm.zju.edu.cn/onlinejudge/showProblem.do?problemCode=3658

Comment: I don't understand what this is supposed to accomplish. It might an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is there an "original" problem that this approach was intended to solve?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I am trying to find a way to analyze a program. KLEE can do that by generating different test cases corresponding to different paths (e.g., if/else goes to different path). It can generate a symbolic expression for each path but does not give all concrete values for inputs. So I am trying to determine the concrete value ranges for different paths.

Answer (score 0):

If your conditions are boolean, you can use (lambda) functions for that. Using your example:

```
conditions = [lambda x:x<50, lambda x:x=>50]
```

Or you can define your functions using `def` and reference them by name inside the list of conditions.